# Stop wordpress from sending out moderation emails

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble with my wordpress installation sending out emails to the site admin 
*every time* a comment is up for moderation.
This also goes for spam comments which results in the site admin getting alot of junk emails in his inbox.

Every time I google this problem I end up with the answer "Just go to Settings -> Discussion and unclick 'A comment is held for moderation'" but unfortunately this is not helping me.

So, here are my settings (some of these may be irrelevant):

1. I'm using wordpress' built in comment-system. No disqus or facebook comments.
2. I've installed the Akismet-plugin. I did try to disable the plugin, but I still get the emails.
3. Both "Anyone posts a comment" and "A comment is held for moderation" is NOT checked under "Settings" -> "Discussion" -> "E-mail me whenever" on the sites.
4. You do not have to be logged in to write a comment
5. The WP installation is originally a Wordpress MU installation, but I've upgraded to 3.x so it's now build into the regular wordpress installation. The installation run many blogs with different domain names and the problem occurs on all blogs AFAIK.
6. Most of the blogs are using the "Yashfa BRANDED!" theme

The moderation email looks like this:

---

Subject: [SITENAME] Please moderate: "Test spam comments"

---

Body:

```
A new comment on the post 78 "Test spam comments" is waiting for your approval

http://url/test-spam-comments/

Author : djqw21208ryfg23 (IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX , XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  
E-mail :     fweuh3298f9wefg923g329@jkg23ru89g9werhj239r8h238t923.asdfhio  
URL    : http://feg239r239f9fg7329rfg322379fg23f3  
Whois  : http://ws.arin.net/cgi-bin/whois.pl?queryinput=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX


Comment:  
ugly spam comment goes here...


Approve it: http://url/wp-admin/comment.php?action=mac&c=XXXXX  
Delete it: http://url/wp-admin/comment.php?action=cdc&c=XXXXX  
Spam it: http://url/wp-admin/comment.php?action=cdc&dt=spam&c=XXXXX  
Currently 0 comments are waiting for approval.   

Please visit the moderation panel:
http://url/wp-admin/moderation.php
```

---

Is there a setting I've forgotten to check?
Why do I keep on getting these emails even though I've turned off the email-settings under "Settings" -> "Discussion"?

Comment: Are the discussion settings global or per blog?

Comment: @MaxGherkins it's per blog. A global setting that overrides this  would explain it, but I can't find any global setting like that.

Comment: Do have access to the database of your blogs? If so, could you post the result of this query `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE "%notify"`

Comment: ..and if you have multiple options tables like wp_2_options, wp_3_options for those as well.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the database. I do not have a table named wp_options, but I do have one for each blog.
I did test with the first blog:
SELECT * FROM wp_1_options WHERE option_name LIKE "%notify";
gives my field option_value empty (null).
Just to be sure I did go into admin and enabled "Anyone posts a comment" and "A comment is held for moderation". The option value was then set to 1 on both.

Comment: Here are the full MySQL query:
mysql> SELECT * FROM wp_1_options WHERE option_name LIKE "%notify";
+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
| option_id | blog_id | option_name       | option_value | autoload |
+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
|        10 |       0 | comments_notify   |              | yes      | 
|        32 |       0 | moderation_notify |              | yes      | 
+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

Comment: I did try to change the option_value from NULL to 0 on  comments_notify and moderation_notify but it didn't seem to help.

I also see that the blog_id is always set to 0 on all blogs in this table. Is this normal? I guess that's something from the MU migration?

On a side note: the option_id changes from blog to blog:
wp_1_options: option_id 32 = moderation_notify
wp_50_options: option_id 31 = moderation_notify
wp_100_options: option_id 30 = moderation_notify
Could this cause any problems?

Comment: The blog_id is always 0 in my setup, too. 
Not sure about the option_id thing. it always the same in my tables (10, 30) ...

Comment: as the settings look alright in the DB, too i don't have a clue whats causing this. maybe ask the question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ... good luck !

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will try over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ then :)

Comment: BTW - This scenario happened to me after migrating an old site with a bunch of individual posts able to accept comments, despite the site-wide default set to deny comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem: wordpresses sending out mails. I host some wordpress blogs for other people, who sometimes drop off the planet and don't look after them any more. I do have full access to the database, so this is my method of closing wordpress down for comments and disabeling the mail:

(this assumes the default table-prefix of wp_*)

There are  two options that influence the sending of mail: comments_notify and moderation_notify.  I set both to false:

```
  UPDATE wp_options SET option_value=0 WHERE option_name LIKE "%notify";
```

I also delete all the un-approved comments:

```
  DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_approved` = 0;
```

and close all the posts and pages for further comments:

```
  UPDATE  `wp_posts` SET comment_status='closed';
```

and then there's still the mailqueue to clean up .... :-(

Comment: Personally, I would not change the 'notify' option since it is a nice check that  things are not degrading in the background.